# Clean way to test that a function has been applied to each item of a collection?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I want to test a function similar to the following:

```
def some_function_under_test(some_list_type_arg: List):
    map(some_other_function, some_list_type_arg)
```

What is a good and clean way to unittest this?

I am going to mock the `map` function

```
assert map_mock.called_once_with(...)
```

but what if the function will be written this way

```
for i in some_list_type_arg:
    some_other_function(i)
```

How do I test this function independently from its implementation, i.e. not tying the test to the `map` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert that `some_other_function` was called on each element by mocking it with a mock that just calls the original function, e.g.:

```
import unittest

from mock import patch, Mock, call


def some_other_function(x):
    return 2 * x


def some_function_under_test(some_list_type_arg):
    return map(some_other_function, some_list_type_arg)


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_thing(self):
        with patch('__main__.some_other_function', Mock(side_effect=some_other_function)) as other_mock:
            self.assertEqual(list(some_function_under_test([1, 2, 3])),
                             [2, 4, 6])
        self.assertEqual(other_mock.call_args_list,
                         [call(1), call(2), call(3)])


unittest.main()
```